# Substring function in C

Tags: c, substring, c-strings, function-definition

I'm trying to make substring function in C, which is pretty logical and easy, but for some reason it prints out symbols. I've checked on the internet multiple times, compared to other people's function but I can't find the exact reason why my code doesn't work.

```
#define MAX 50

char* substring(char string[], int indexBeginning, int indexEnd) {
    const char *result[MAX];
    int n= 0;

    for (int i = indexBeginning; i <= indexEnd; i++) {
        result[n++] = string[i];
    }
    result[n] = '\0';

    return result;
}
```

Comment: `result` is 1) Incorrect type (should be `char []`) 2) Is local and cannot be returned

Comment: I thought you can get the function to return whole string if it's allocated in heap, by using malloc or just declaring it as const?

Comment: `malloc` - yes, `const` - no. What made you believe so?

Comment: `result[n++] = string[i]` assigns a `char` value (promoted to `int`) to a `char *` pointer object. That requires a diagnostic.  `result` is an array of pointers, not an array of characters.

Comment: Please turn on compiler warnings and see all the things wrong with this code.

Comment: `result` is a local, automatic variable. A pointer to it cannot be returned from the function, because it is destroyed.

Comment: @EugeneI think I saw it somewhere on the internet, not sure.

Comment: @JustCaused I think you're confusing `const` and `static`. With the declaration `static char result[MAX]`, you could `return result;`. But every time you call the function, the old `result` will be overwritten.

Comment: @JustCaused You are probably talking about `static`. But it has its own pitfalls.

Comment: Yeah, there it is! I added static and removed * inside declaration and it works! Thanks everybody for your quick reply.

Comment: Make sure you understand what `static` means. It is not just a magical word to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This array declaration

```
const char *result[MAX];
```

is incorrect. It seems you mean

```
char result[MAX];
```

But in any case you may not use the array as a returned expression

```
return result;
```

because the array is a local object of the function that will not be alive after exiting the function.

Also this loop

```
for (int i = indexBeginning; i <= indexEnd; i++) {
    result[n++] = string[i];
}
```

is unsafe because there is no check that specified indices are valid for the source string.

And the function itself should be declared like

```
char * substring( const char string[], size_t pos, size_t n );
```

The function can be defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * substring( const char s[], size_t pos, size_t n )
{
    char *result = NULL;
    
    size_t length = strlen( s );
    if ( pos < length )
    {
        n = n <= length - pos ? n : length - pos;
        
        result = malloc( n + 1 );
        
        if ( result != NULL )
        {
            result[n] = '\0';
            
            memcpy( result, s + pos, n );
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "Hello World!";
    
    char *word = substring( s, 0, 5 );
    
    if ( word ) puts( word );
    
    free( word );
    
    word = substring( s, 6, 5 );

    if ( word ) puts( word );
    
    free( word );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: I was confused about const instead of static, which seems to work now. In function before I asserted indices, but thanks for your advice!